# Too many argument error when I add a column in stored procedure to display in my SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have added a new column to my table and I want the same to reflect in my SSRS report which takes values from a stored procedure.But when I run my report I am getting 'Too many arguments in my stored procedure' error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting means the stored procedure is expecting fewer arguments than are configured for the dataset. Open the dataset configuration and click *Refresh Fields*. You might need to clean up now-unused parameters and or perhaps update the SProc. Also, you will need to alter your SProc anyway in order to add new fields. *Refresh Fields* will take care of that too.

Comment: I refreshed the fields and still I am getting the error. I am clueless.

Comment: To add the new column , I first added it in the table. Then added the same column/field into the existing stored procedure. After that I went to the SSRS report and added the same field under the main dataset. In the expression for it , I gave the query to display that field. I refreshed the dataset and then ran my SSRS report which gives the above error to me then. @oglester

Comment: I don't think adding a field to the results of the sproc would cause the error. It actually should still work, excluding the new columns. Are there other datasets that might be having the issue (confirm this is the culprit)?

Comment: There is just 1 dataset that is being used in this SSRS report. @oglester

Comment: The only thought I have now, is to delete the dataset and re-create it.

Comment: Hmm , it got resolved. I used the production server where when I updated my stored proc and refreshed the dataset fields. The new field populated itself. Thanks for your help! @oglester